# Azure System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException

Tags: web-services, azure

I use a web service on a server and it works OK. Now I want to transfer my site to an Azure server. For now I created a free web site on azure to test it.

It is a Silverlight application that calls a service to create a report.

When I call this service I have the following error

error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
   at C1.Util.FontSubSet.#e.#cA.#Kn(FontSubSet owner, String tableName)
   at C1.Util.FontSubSet.GetFontTableStream(String name)
   at C1.Util.FontSubSet.#TDd()
   at C1.Util.FontSubSet.Init()
   at C1.Util.FontSubSet.GetFontSubSet(FontKey fk)
   at C1.C1Preview.C1PrintDocument.#ydd(String s, String fontName, Boolean fontBold, Boolean fontItalic, Boolean updateDocumentFonts)
   at C1.C1Preview.C1PrintDocument.#zdd(String s, String fontName, Byte fontCharSet, FontStyle fontStyle)
   at C1.C1Preview.RenderText.InternalResolvingFinished()
   at C1.C1Preview.RenderObject.ResolvingFinished()
   at C1.C1Report.Layout.RenderDirect(ILengthCacheProvider lcp, RenderObject ro, RenderFragment rf, Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height)
   at C1.C1Report.Layout.RenderDirect(ILengthCacheProvider lcp, RenderObject ro, RenderFragment rf, RectangleD bounds)
   at C1.C1Report.Field.#RLd(ExportFilter export, Layout layout, RectangleD bounds, String str, Boolean rtf, Double lineWidthTw, Int32 firstCharIndex, Int32 length)
   at C1.C1Report.Field.Render(Layout layout, Double x, Double y, Boolean measure)
   at C1.C1Report.Field.Render(Layout layout, Double x, Double y)
   at C1.C1Report.Section.Render(Boolean keepPage, Group ownerGroup)
   at C1.C1Report.Layout.#fMd(Section s)
   at C1.C1Report.Layout.StartDoc()
   at C1.C1Report.C1Report.RenderFirstPass(Boolean releaseDocument)
   at C1.C1Report.C1Report.#fNd()
   at C1.C1Report.C1Report.#dNd(ExportFilter filter, Boolean reuse)
   at C1.C1Report.C1Report.RenderToStream(Stream stream, FileFormatEnum fmt, String idPrefix, String fileName)
   at C1.C1Report.C1Report.RenderToStream(Stream stream, FileFormatEnum fmt)
   at Gestion1.Web.RapportS.GetReportCommunique()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope> `
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided stack trace it looks like you are attempting to run report tools from ComponentOne on the server.

The issue is caused by access to APIs that are restricted from use by Azure Web Site instances for security and performance reasons.  The native GDI rendering methods are among these restricted APIs.

See the post from Jim Cheshire towards the end of [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4a6eb43-0013-435f-9d11-00ee26a8d017/report-viewer-error-on-export-pdf-or-excel-from-azure-web-sites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Until and unless these restrictions are relaxed (which they may not be) your options are to move the service to a Cloud Service instance, or move to another component that does not use native GDI methods to render.